# Prematurely arrested players

Tags: story, in-game-continuity

In short, I have 2 players that had stolen some valued items that were crafty in how they would avoid leaving a trail (changing clothes, altering directions via water).  Im happy to reward their thorough plan to escape with keeping the gear, but plan to have a secret order track and arrest them to drive a key plot point in the arc.

However nearing the end of a gaming session, I had agents of the secret order confront them to end the session on a tense cliffhanger.. except I have jumped the gun (they wouldnt have the info needed yet to find them, chronologically  as the players were discussing and figuring out how their escape had ultimately failed).

**Could I get some suggestions on how I can massage this back into a fair and believable story, or have I failed as a DM?..**

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]! To offer advice on handling this situation the site needs more details. A brief outline of the PCs' plan (and if it went down flawlessly) and a description of the secret order (and the resources available to it) would be a good start. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: What system are you using? Does it have magic,  is technology. These effect possible answers

Comment: As Garret says, system and genre can inform an answer. But can you clarify exactly what you hope to correct? Is it that the agents found the heroes at all? Too soon?